# Microsoft Appsource scraper is not returning all the values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am using BeautifulSoup in Python to extract data from https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=power-bi-visuals&page=3

And this is what I am getting right up to this point.

[image: obnoxious screen shot of a table of results]

The code that is doing this is:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import pandas as pd
import re

# Base URL without the page number
base_url = 'https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/apps?product=power-bi-visuals&page=3'

all_data = {'Title': [], 'Owner': [], 'Ratings': [], 'Count of Rates': [], 'Page': []}

try:
    # Loop through pages 1 to 10 (for example)
    for page_num in range(1, 2):  # Change the range as needed
        url = base_url.format(page_num)

        # Send a GET request to the URL
        response = requests.get(url)

        # Introduce a delay to wait for the page to potentially load dynamic content
        time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the delay as needed (e.g., 5 seconds)

        # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            # Parse the HTML content using BeautifulSoup
            soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

            # Find all elements with the specified classes
            elementsTitle = soup.find_all('span', attrs={"class": 'title'})
            elementsOwner = soup.find_all('span', attrs={"class": 'publisher'})
            elementsRatings = soup.find_all('label', attrs={"class": 'detailsRatingAvgNumOfStars'})
            elementsCountOfRates = soup.find_all('span', attrs={"class": 'detailsRatingNumOfRatingText'})
                
            # Extract text content from elements and append to all_data dictionary
            for title, owner, rating, CountOfRates in zip(elementsTitle, elementsOwner, elementsRatings, elementsCountOfRates):
                # Find span elements inside the price div


                all_data['Title'].append(title.text.strip())
                all_data['Owner'].append(owner.text.strip())
                all_data['Ratings'].append(rating.text.strip())
                all_data['Count of Rates'].append(int(re.search(r'\((\d+) ratings\)', CountOfRates.text).group(1)))
                all_data['Page'].append(page_num)

            print(f'Page {page_num} content processed')

        else:
            print(f'Failed to fetch page {page_num}:', response.status_code)

except Exception as e:
    print("An error occurred:", str(e))

# Convert all_data to pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(all_data)

# Export DataFrame to Excel file
df.to_excel('xyz.xlsx', index=False)
print('Data written to xyz.xlsx')
```

My problem is that I want more data. I tried pull up the full page and found values labeled `priceModel` that tell me if a visual is free or not. But whenever I try to pull the price data up, nothing is returned. You will find in the next image what data I want to extract. I tried using HTML Price that is div value but it returns nothing, tried by the text inside of span but it also returns nothing.

[image: card for a particular app; price "free" highlighted]

Comment: If the page you're accessing is "dynamic" (JavaScript?) then you should try using *selenium* rather than *requests* in conjunction with artificial delays

Comment: I already delay the page loading by time sleep (5). At first it didn't return title, Owner, and other data. Now it does. However I can't use selenium due to drive is not aligned with my chrome version.

Comment: if page uses JavaScript to add element then you can't use `requests` and `Beautifulsoup` because they don't run `JavaScript` and using `delay` can't help. And you may need `Selenium` for this. And you can use it not only with Chrome but also with `Firefox` or `Microsoft Edge`. And if you have problem with `Chrome` then maybe download correct version of driver for your Chrome and correct version of Selenium for your Chrome.

Comment: you could crop image - to remove white space.

Comment: I would crop it in future (after god well)

Comment: Please don't add extra indentation to Python code; it gets harder to copy/paste, and easily scrolls off the screen on small devices. On the desktop version of this site, you can paste your code, then select the pasted block and type ctrl-K to correctly format your code with indentations preserved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you can get the data without `bs4`.

There's an endpoint you can query that has all the data you need.

Here's a working example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests
from tabulate import tabulate

endpoint = "https://appsource.microsoft.com/view/tiledata?"

payload = {
    "ReviewsMyCommentsFilter": "true",
    "country": "US",
    "entityType": "App",
    "page": "NONE",
    "product": "power-bi-visuals",
    "region": "ALL",
}

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) "
                  "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "
                  "Chrome/119.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 Edg/119.0.0.0"
}

app_data = []

with requests.Session() as s:
    response = s.get(endpoint, headers=headers, params=payload)
    apps = response.json()["apps"]
    
    # 60 apps per page + 1 to account for remainder
    total_pages = apps["count"] // 60 + 1

    for page in range(1, total_pages + 1):
        payload["page"] = page
        response = s.get(endpoint, headers=headers, params=payload)
        apps = response.json()["apps"]

        app_data += [
            {
                "name": app["title"].strip(),
                "owner": app["publisher"].strip(),
                "price": "Free" if not app["hasPrices"] else "Paid",
                "certified": "Yes" if app["tags"] else "No",
                "rating": app["AverageRating"],
                "ratingCount": app["NumberOfRatings"],
            }
            for app in apps["dataList"]
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(app_data, columns=app_data[0].keys())
df = df.sort_values(by=["ratingCount"], ascending=False)
df.to_csv("powerbi_visuals.csv", index=False)

print(tabulate(df, headers="keys", tablefmt="psql", showindex=False))
```

This should output all the data for all the pages.

Sample output:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+----------+---------------+
| name                                                                    | owner                                                                 | price   | certified   |   rating |   ratingCount |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------+-------------+----------+---------------|
| HierarchySlicer                                                         | DataScenarios                                                         | Free    | Yes         |  3.89    |           273 |
| Chiclet Slicer                                                          | Microsoft Corporation                                                 | Free    | Yes         |  3.907   |           247 |
| Timeline Slicer                                                         | Microsoft Corporation                                                 | Free    | Yes         |  3.336   |           241 |
| Visio Visual                                                            | Microsoft Corporation                                                 | Free    | Yes         |  2.964   |           192 |
| Text Filter                                                             | Microsoft Corporation                                                 | Free    | Yes         |  4.124   |           177 |
| Gantt                                                                   | Microsoft Corporation                                                 | Free    | Yes         |  3.13    |           161 |
| Word Cloud                                                              | Microsoft Corporation                                                 | Free    | Yes         |  4.229   |           140 |
| Power KPI Matrix                                                        | Microsoft Corporation                                                 | Free    | Yes         |  3.728   |           136 |
| Tachometer                                                              | Annik Inc                                                             | Free    | Yes         |  4.326   |           129 |
| Radar Chart                                                             | Microsoft Corporation                                                 | Free    | Yes         |  3.574   |           129 |

and many more...
```

Comment: Your code does everything right, but it seems it doesn't return price?

Comment: I don't see a price value on the site. It's either Free or Additional purchase may be required.

Comment: you are correct. But I can't return any of them.

Comment: I've updated the answer.

Comment: Great, it work's fine. 
Can you help figure out how did you know what is the end points?

Comment: @OnlySalman go check out your Developer's Tools in your browser and explore the XHR in the Networking tab.